# What is the passive form of "I saw Adam going to market"

Tags: sentence-structure

I am trying like this

Adam going to market was seen by me.

Is this is correct?

I am confused about the subject.

Adam going to market

Comment: Don't forget, a common use of the passive is to be subjectless: "Adam was seen going to the market" or "Adam has been seen going to the market"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**He saw Adam** | going to the market.

First, simplify it: **He saw Adam** becomes **Adam was seen by him**.

The subject is I and the verb is saw and the object is Adam.

Going to the market is "extra": **Adam was seen by him going to the market**.

I changed the pronoun because the passive with I would be a little odd there.

Only the part of the sentence with the main verb can be made passive.

going to market can be analyzed as "when" I saw him. It can be analyzed as an adverbial phrase.

However, When going to the market, he saw Adam. is another sentence. And: He saw Adam when he was going to the market is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found a note from another place: _Adam's going to the market was seen by him._ Also: _Adam, going to the market, was seen by him_.

Comment: That is awkward. If you are using the passive, it's best to be very clear.

Answer (score 4):

*Passive* is a cyclic rule. That means it applies to a **clause**, not to a sentence. There are two clauses in this sentence, so it doesn't have a passive form.

In addition, passive can only be applied to transitive clauses that have both a subject and a direct object. The first clause of the example sentence is intransitive, with no direct object, and therefore that clause doesn't have a passive form, either.

Any question that asks you for the "passive form" of a complex sentence or of an intransitive clause is a stupid question, written by someone who didn't understand English grammar, and you should not attempt to answer it. If you want to learn English, anyway.

Comment: john: my sentence is not a complex sentence. That sentence is a simple sentence.

Comment: @AsifIqbal No, I'm afraid John (Professor of Linguistics) is correct ;)

Comment: +1 Some grammars (for example CaGEL) analyse *Adam* in the OP's sentence as a Direct Object and the clause *going to the market* as a Catenative Complement (presumably in some kind of object control construction). One of the reasons for this, I believe, is that the clause can indeed be passivised: *Adam was seen going to the market*. I'm not sure I dig that analysis, though.

Comment: My explanation is wrong? Somebody has it in for me around here. ELLers require simple examples and explanations. Who is the "you" are you addressing in your second paragraph?**He saw Adam going to market** contains something that can be made into a passive: Adam was seen by him.  "going to market" can be viewed here as invariable. In any event, at this level, an example works fine. You can only learn grammar by examples first.

Comment: (1) A complex sentence is a sentence containing a subordinate clause. The subordinate clause in the OS is the intransitive  gerund clause _Adam going to market_. (2) Practically any sentence "contains something that can be made into a passive" if you can take any verb and any noun from any clause and combine them any way you think counts as "passive".

Comment: Someone is removing my posts. I had a response here. People on this site are such sour grapes. I guess I am not allowed to disagree with a head honcho. [sigh] One wonders what that says about power systems and how they work in this internet age....I do not analyze the sentence in the same way that you do. *I saw Adam going to market* can be analyzed as: I saw Adam + going to market. He left June sleeping on the bed. He left June + sleeping on the bed.

Comment: @Lambie: I have no idea what "the point" is, and I haven't deleted anybody's post. I'm just trying to point out that "passive" does have a specific grammatical meaning in English (though not in all languages) and so does "complex sentence". If questions use these terms in different ways, it's difficult if not impossible to answer them correctly. That's all. Feel free to disagree, and use them any way you like, but don't be surprised if you get misunderstood.